# Dataweave problem with mapping from message to another message

Tags: mapping, dataweave, mulesoft

This is my input Json format

```
{
  "P2": {
    "queue": {
      "tst-bp-1": {
        "smsTo": "John Test1: 06-12345678, Emilo Test1: 06-87654321",
        "mailTo": "johntest1@test.com, emilotest1@test.com"
      },
      "tst-bp-2": {
        "smsTo": "John Test2: 06-12345678, Emilo Test2: 06-87654321",
        "mailTo": "johntest2@test.com, emilotest2@test.com"
      }
    },
    "host": {
      "systemP@testbp.com": {
        "smsTo": "Jeff Test1: 06-12345678, Tim Test1: 06-87654321",
        "mailTo": "Jeff test1@test.com, timtest1@test.com"
      },
      "systemXAF@testbp.com": {
        "smsTo": "Jeff Test1: 06-12345678, Tim Test1: 06-87654321",
        "mailTo": "Jeff test1@test.com, timtest1@test.com"
      }
    },
    "cert": {
      "getMySystemname@werbung.com": {
        "smsTo": "Jeff Test1: 06-12345678, Tim Test1: 06-87654321",
        "mailTo": "Jeff test1@test.com, timtest1@test.com"
      }
    }
  },
  "P3": {
    "queue": {
      "acc-bp-1": {
        "smsTo": "John Test1: 06-12345678, Emilo Test1: 06-87654321",
        "mailTo": "johntest1@test.com, emilotest1@test.com"
      }
    },
    "host": {
      "ACCsystem@testbp.com": {
        "smsTo": "Jeff Test1: 06-12345678, Tim Test1: 06-87654321",
        "mailTo": "Jeff test1@test.com, timtest1@test.com"
      }
    },
    "etc": null
  }
}
```

And this must be the result:

```
[
  {
    "systemName": "tst-bp-1",
    "priority": "P2",
    "systemType": "queue"
    "smsTo": "John Test1: 06-12345678, Emilo Test1: 06-87654321",
    "mailTo: "johntest1@test.com, emilotest1@test.com"
  },
  {
    "systemName": "tst-bp-2",
    "priority": "P2",
    "systemType": "queue",
    "smsTo": "John Test2: 06-12345678, Emilo Test2: 06-87654321",
    "mailTo: "johntest2@test.com, emilotest2@test.com"
  },
  {
    "systemName": "systemP@testbp.com",
    "priority": "P2",
    "systemType": "host",
    "smsTo": "Jeff Test1: 06-12345678, Tim Test1: 06-87654321",
    "mailTo: "Jeff test1@test.com, timtest1@test.com"
  },
  {
    "systemName": "systemXAF@testbp.com",
    "priority": "P2",
    "systemType": "host",
    "smsTo": "Jeff Test1: 06-12345678, Tim Test1: 06-87654321",
    "mailTo: "Jeff test1@test.com, timtest1@test.com"
  },
  {
    "systemName": "getMySystemname@werbung.com",
    "priority": "P2",
    "systemType": "cert",
    "smsTo": "Jeff Test1: 06-12345678, Tim Test1: 06-87654321",
    "mailTo: "Jeff test1@test.com, timtest1@test.com"
  },
  [
  {
    "systemName": "acc-bp-1",
    "priority": "P3",
    "systemType": "queue"
    "smsTo": "John Test1: 06-12345678, Emilo Test1: 06-87654321",
    "mailTo: "johntest1@test.com, emilotest1@test.com"
  },
  {
    "systemName": "ACCsystem@testbp.com",
    "priority": "P3",
    "systemType": "host",
    "smsTo": "Jeff Test1: 06-12345678, Tim Test1: 06-87654321",
    "mailTo: "Jeff test1@test.com, timtest1@test.com"
  }
]
```

I have some things tried like this:

```
flatten(payload pluck (priority, systemType) -> 
    systemType pluck ((systemName, systemData) -> {
        systemName: systemName,
        priority: priority,
        systemType: systemType,
        smsTo: systemData."smsTo",
        mailTo: systemData."mailTo"
    })
)
```

But the code is not working. Help me please. The problem is I guess to flatten this array to the wanted object.
Well I have to add more details. But there is not much more detail, so I have tried the code in de playground of dataweave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with such problems, you can try to first pick each "parts" of payload one by one using a combination of `entriesOf` and `flatMap`s and then just map it to the final output. The `flatMap` will take care of the nested arrays that `entriesOf` will create. You can also use `pluck` with `flatten`s but it will require you to keep track of nested brackets and could make the code harder to read in my opinion. But if you find like that better, you can convert the following easily to the other version

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json skipNullOn = "arrays" //skip null elements in array to remove the entries like "etc": null
---
entriesOf(payload) flatMap ((priority) -> 
    entriesOf(priority.value) flatMap ((systemType) -> 
        entriesOf(systemType.value) flatMap ((systemCommunication) -> (
            {
                systemName: systemCommunication.key,
                priority: priority.key,
                systemType: systemType.key,
                smsTo: systemCommunication.value.smsTo,
                mailTo: systemCommunication.value.mailTo,
            }
        ))
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks very much Harshank Bansal, also for your explanation how to solve these kind of dataweave problems !

Comment: No problem. As per my experience, if you need one array from one simple object, use pluck. If you need one array from a complex object, more often then not `entriesOf` + `flatMap` makes the problem easier. Also, giving meaningful names to variables helps a lot in such scenarios.